# Is it possible to iterate over the row values of a column in KQL to feed each value through a function

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am applying the series_decompose_anomalies algorithm to time data coming from multiple meters. Currently, I am using the ADX dashboard feature to feed my meter identifier as a parameter into the algorithm and return my anomalies and scores as a table.

```
let dt = 3hr;
Table
| where meter_ID == dashboardParameter
| make-series num=avg(value) on timestamp from _startTime to _endTime step dt
| extend (anomalies,score,baseline) = series_decompose_anomalies( num, 3,-1, 'linefit')
| mv-expand timestamp, num, baseline, anomalies, score
| where anomalies ==1 
| project dashboardParameter, todatetime(timestamp), toreal(num), toint(anomalies), toreal(score)
```

I would like to bulk process all my meters in one go and return a table with all anomalies found across them. Is it possible to feed an array as an iterable in KQL or something similar to allow my parameter to change multiple times in a single run?

Comment: Please note that you've been given an answer over 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `by meter_ID` to [make-series](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-seriesoperator)
(and remove `| where meter_ID == dashboardParameter`)

```
| make-series num=avg(value) on timestamp from _startTime to _endTime step dt by meter_ID
```

P.S.
Anomaly can be positive (num > baseline => flag = 1) or negative (num < baseline => flag = -1)

###### Demo

```
let _step       = 1h;
let _endTime    = toscalar(TransformedServerMetrics | summarize max(Timestamp));
let _startTime  = _endTime - 12h;
TransformedServerMetrics
| make-series num = avg(Value) on Timestamp from _startTime to _endTime step _step by SQLMetrics
| extend (flag, score, baseline) = series_decompose_anomalies(num , 3,-1, 'linefit')
| mv-expand Timestamp to typeof(datetime), num to typeof(real), flag to typeof(int), score to typeof(real), baseline to typeof(real)
| where flag != 0
```

| SQLMetrics | num | Timestamp | flag | score | baseline |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| write_bytes | 169559910.91717172 | 2022-06-14T15:00:30.2395884Z | -1 | -3.4824039875238131 | 170205132.25708669 |
| cpu_time_ms | 17.369556143036036 | 2022-06-14T17:00:30.2395884Z | 1 | 7.8874529842826 | 11.04372634506527 |
| percent_complete | 0.04595588235294118 | 2022-06-14T22:00:30.2395884Z | 1 | 25.019464868749985 | 0.004552738927738928 |
| blocking_session_id | -5 | 2022-06-14T22:00:30.2395884Z | -1 | -25.019464868749971 | -0.49533799533799527 |
| pending_disk_io_count | 0.0019675925925925924 | 2022-06-14T23:00:30.2395884Z | 1 | 6.4686836384225685 | 0.00043773741690408352 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/SampleMetrics?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3WPzU7DMBCE75X6DsupseRIBI4obwAH1IprtE02rYV/InsTUtSHx04oiUD45tndmW80MVSBqYP5lVCcn7YbnWSyzUEZmmV2oUaNPjt4tKF13lCzJz%20QfyH2qg5whdAbg159Ehgcs3QbGE0nxM0xfj3PnuXin0PxkEL/c95urtHwnfJAXlEA25t4jsMpe0PdkwBn4ScMWu/MOondkjQVneseL7B/fV4l0MhxDbJW40lCqJ0nCUcMpJWNGSXM6VVDtTOdC1ShdQZ11LJEJOFR5oWEXdpvFe/ExD3kNHYYjRfCSMSXjlybNcjEURdyKrUMPKGOYmJZqcqy%20Eb7u3tD/T1JFB9niieT210J918sZvOj9QEAAA==)